# tikz scale not congruence in Tex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikzscale, picture-mode

I have code for a figure below

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,font=\footnotesize]
 \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
 \coordinate (B) at (0:1.5);
 \coordinate (C) at ([shift={(B)}]-50:1);
 \coordinate (D) at ([shift={(C)}]-160:1.5);
 \coordinate (E) at (240:1);
 \path ($(A)+(0.5,2)$) coordinate (A')
 ($(B)+(0.5,2)$) coordinate (B')
 ($(C)+(0.5,2)$) coordinate (C')
 ($(D)+(0.5,2)$) coordinate (D')
 ($(E)+(0.5,2)$) coordinate (E');
 \fill[left color=gray!70,right color=gray!70, middle color=gray!40, opacity=1.2] (A')--(B')--(C')--(D')--(E')--cycle;
 \fill[left color=gray!90,right color=gray!40, middle color=gray!60, opacity=1.2] (E)--(E')--(D')--(D)--cycle;
 \fill[left color=gray!90,right color=gray!40, middle color=gray!60, opacity=1.2] (C)--(D)--(D')--(C')--cycle;
 \draw[line width=0.2pt] (E)--(E')--(A')--(B')--(C')--(C)--(D)--cycle
 (C')--(D')--(E') (D)--(D');
 \draw (D)node[below]{Khối lăng trụ};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And this is picture

[image]

When I use option scale=0.7 then the picture as figure below

[image]

What problem did happend in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the fact that symbolic coordinates do not get transformed. However, in

```
 \coordinate (C) at ([shift={(B)}]-50:1);
 \coordinate (D) at ([shift={(C)}]-160:1.5);
```

the shifts get effectively transformed because of the way Ti*k*Z parses these. So you need to replace those expressions by

```
 \coordinate (C) at ($(-50:1)+(B)$);
 \coordinate (D) at ($(-160:1.5)+(C)$);
```

to obtain

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,font=\footnotesize]
 \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
 \coordinate (B) at (0:1.5);
 \coordinate (C) at ($(-50:1)+(B)$);
 \coordinate (D) at ($(-160:1.5)+(C)$);
 \coordinate (E) at (240:1);
 \path ($(A)+(0.5,2)$) coordinate (A')
 ($(B)+(0.5,2)$) coordinate (B')
 ($(C)+(0.5,2)$) coordinate (C')
 ($(D)+(0.5,2)$) coordinate (D')
 ($(E)+(0.5,2)$) coordinate (E');
 \fill[left color=gray!70,right color=gray!70, middle color=gray!40, opacity=1.2] (A')--(B')--(C')--(D')--(E')--cycle;
 \fill[left color=gray!90,right color=gray!40, middle color=gray!60, opacity=1.2] (E)--(E')--(D')--(D)--cycle;
 \fill[left color=gray!90,right color=gray!40, middle color=gray!60, opacity=1.2] (C)--(D)--(D')--(C')--cycle;
 \draw[line width=0.2pt] (E)--(E')--(A')--(B')--(C')--(C)--(D)--cycle
 (C')--(D')--(E') (D)--(D');
 \draw (D)node[below]{Khoi lang tru};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7,font=\footnotesize]
 \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
 \coordinate (B) at (0:1.5);
 \coordinate (C) at ($(-50:1)+(B)$);
 \coordinate (D) at ($(-160:1.5)+(C)$);
 \coordinate (E) at (240:1);
 \path ($(A)+(0.5,2)$) coordinate (A')
 ($(B)+(0.5,2)$) coordinate (B')
 ($(C)+(0.5,2)$) coordinate (C')
 ($(D)+(0.5,2)$) coordinate (D')
 ($(E)+(0.5,2)$) coordinate (E');
 \fill[left color=gray!70,right color=gray!70, middle color=gray!40, opacity=1.2] (A')--(B')--(C')--(D')--(E')--cycle;
 \fill[left color=gray!90,right color=gray!40, middle color=gray!60, opacity=1.2] (E)--(E')--(D')--(D)--cycle;
 \fill[left color=gray!90,right color=gray!40, middle color=gray!60, opacity=1.2] (C)--(D)--(D')--(C')--cycle;
 \draw[line width=0.2pt] (E)--(E')--(A')--(B')--(C')--(C)--(D)--cycle
 (C')--(D')--(E') (D)--(D');
 \draw (D)node[below]{Khoi lang tru};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, you may slightly simplify your picture by saying

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,font=\footnotesize]
 \path (0,0) coordinate (A) (0:1.5) coordinate (B)
 ++ (-50:1) coordinate (C) ++ (-160:1.5) coordinate (D)
 (240:1) coordinate (E);
 \path ($(A)+(0.5,2)$) coordinate (A')
 ($(B)+(0.5,2)$) coordinate (B')
 ($(C)+(0.5,2)$) coordinate (C')
 ($(D)+(0.5,2)$) coordinate (D')
 ($(E)+(0.5,2)$) coordinate (E');
 \fill[left color=gray!70,right color=gray!70, middle color=gray!40, opacity=1.2] (A')--(B')--(C')--(D')--(E')--cycle;
 \fill[left color=gray!90,right color=gray!40, middle color=gray!60, opacity=1.2] (E)--(E')--(D')--(D)--cycle;
 \fill[left color=gray!90,right color=gray!40, middle color=gray!60, opacity=1.2] (C)--(D)--(D')--(C')--cycle;
 \draw[line width=0.2pt] (E)--(E')--(A')--(B')--(C')--(C)--(D)--cycle
 (C')--(D')--(E') (D)--(D');
 \draw (D)node[below]{Khoi lang tru};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Please note also that my editor does not deal with the special characters in `Khối lăng trụ`, so I had so remove them, sorry.

Comment: Thank you @marmot

Comment: @CaoThànhThái You're welcome! BTW, I really like your picture!